# Effective placeholder in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, placeholder

I have a dictionary which includes integer keys and string values. The keys go up to a number N but include gaps. It there an effective way of filling all gaps up to a specific number? (numeration starts with 1, not 0)

Example:

```
{1: "fdkh", 3: "wnww", 4: "fdngfne", 5: "wqiw", 7: "sdfsdf"}
 N = 9
```

The result should be:

```
{1: "fdkh", 3: "wnww", 4: "fdngfne", 5: "wqiw", 7: "sdfsdf", 2: "placeholder", 6: "placeholder", 8: "placeholder", 9: "placeholder"}
```

Of course I can loop manually through it, but is there a smarter way to do that?

Comment: Looping would be the way. You could also use a `defaultdict` to have those empty values filled in at the time they're requested instead of beforehand. Also, consider using a `list` instead. A dictionary containing contiguous numeric keys is basically a more complicated list; unless you need certain dictionary operations like removal.

Comment: I have never seen the defauldict, thats in fact a great idea. Thank you! Thats a bit better than the loop.

Answer (score 1):

One quick way to do it (which does admittedly involve a bit of looping) is

```
mydict = dict.fromkeys(range(1,N+1),"placeholder") | {
    1: "fdkh", 3: "wnww", 4: "fdngfne", 5: "wqiw", 7: "sdfsdf"}
```

Though I suspect you might be reaching for `collections.defaultdict`:

```
mydict = defaultdict(lambda: "placeholder",{
    1: "fdkh", 3: "wnww", 4: "fdngfne", 5: "wqiw", 7: "sdfsdf"})
```